# Define lifecycle intercepting methods in the target class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, interceptor

I am reading the section about interceptors in the [java ee tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkedm.html#gkecr) and it states: `"Interceptors for lifecycle callback events (post-create and pre-destroy) may be defined in the target class or in interceptor classes."`

My question is how we can define `lifecycle intercepting callback methods` in target class, since the related annotations (`@PostConstruct`, `@PreDestroy`, etc) define only the corresponding `lifecycle methods`.How can we define them as `intercepting methods` at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

From the same tutorial (emphasis is mine):

> The **@PostCreate** annotation is used to designate a method as a
>   **post-create lifecycle event interceptor**. The **@PreDestroy** annotation is used to designate a method as **a pre-destroy lifecycle
>   event interceptor**.

So this tutorial considers methods annotated with `@PostCreate` and `@PreDestroy` annotations as life cycle interceptors.  Which in actuality they are.

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

Life-cycle call-back methods can be considered as interceptors since `EJB container` invokes (injects) them before or after certain life-cycle events. `Stateless` beans can have `Pre-destruction` and `Post-construction` callbacks, while `stateful` beans, in addition to these two, could have `Activation` and `Passivation` callbacks.

Listing of `EJB 3.0` callbacks can be found in [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ejb/ejb_callbacks.htm).

Comment: @PreDestroy is however a lifecycle callback method. How can it be at the same time intercepring method? Moreover where can I find the doc from the PostCreate annotation?

Comment: We seem to be discussing terminology here. See the addition to my answer.